# Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 Interactive window dicconnected - tried many solutions, can't work

Tags: python, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, ptvs

My issue is : I tried to run Python in the Visual Studio Express Desktop 2015, but the interactive window shows "disconnected". There is an error in the interactive window:

```
An internal error has occurred in the Interactive window.  Please restart Visual Studio.
```

I can't type anything in the interactive window. Tried to restart it, nothing changed.

I have already tried to uninstall and reinstall both Visual Studio and python tool. Error is still there. I googled this problem, someone suggested to install python interpreters also, by following this instruction:[PTVS/wiki/PTVS-Installation](https://github.com/Microsoft/PTVS/wiki/PTVS-Installation) ; So I tried installing the Cpython and IronPython, but still get the same error...

The software is run under windows system. My computer is 64 bit operation system.

Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: I solved this issue by myself. If you have already installed the python tool and interpreters by following the instruction (link pasted above), and still can't work with interactive window, this Visual Studio update package may help you: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/vs2015-update1-vs.aspx; If you want to do this, remember to completely uninstall the whole software. This is an instruction of how completely uninstall. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/heaths/archive/2015/07/17/removing-visual-studio-components-left-behind-after-an-uninstall.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Install latest version and this will resolve
https://github.com/Microsoft/PTVS/releases